# (Python) Selenium Webdriver returns old elements after getting a new url

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, web-scraping

I have a pretty simple process where within a loop, I get a url, wait for certain elements to load using WebDriverWait and then start processing the page source.

The issue I'm having is that it seems like if I don't add explicit wait times between the driver.get(url), webdriver can return elements from the old page rather than the most recent page. If I add explicit (for instance 3 seconds) or call on driver.get(url) twice, the issue gets resolved.

Has any one experienced this issue or know how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you specified implicit time for that driver instance?

Comment: @Santoshsarma I hadn't added implicit time, are you talking about implicitly_wait()? I will give it a try and see if it fixes it. thanks

Comment: Yes. I'm taking about that only.

Comment: You can even try `time.sleep()`, but it's a bit ugly. `implicitly_wait` is what is necessary here though it makes code more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code, and some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have encountered this on firefox with geckodriver and it is because you loaded another page by clicking on an old element. That driver object needs to be refreshed.
Reloading the page needed to traverse worked for me, waiting doesn't help.

```
driver.get(driver.current_url)
```

Edit: Chrome doesn't seem to have this problem and driver can access the elements from the clicked page directly.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a problem on a web browser. That is why after `driver.get(url)` I usually check, if `driver.get()` is successful:

```
driver.get(url)
sleep(n_seconds) #that is not necessary.
if driver.current_url == url:
    #do something
else:
    #try again to get the page or wait more.
```